# Mandar un msgbox por red de una pc a otra

Tags: c, windows, cmd

lo que quiero hacer es bastante básico pero se me han presentado dificultades.
Quiero que básicamente aparezca un cartel con un mensaje como un msgbox, en una pc remotamente enviado desde otra,

> Aspectos a tener en cuenta

-Estas dos pc claramente estan en la misma red y en el mismo grupo de trabajo.

-Ambas pc tienen SO windows8

-el comando net send no funciona en versiones desde win7 o mas

-la solucion no puede ser un programa, me gustaría poder hacerlo todo desde la cmd o como mucho usando C

entonces teniendo todo esto en cuenta no se me ocurre una solucion, desde ya gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe el comando `msg` para el envío de mensajes desde la consola, pero tiene limitaciones, solo funciona para la versiones PRO.

Antes de lanzar el comando ve a "Abrir configuración de red" / "Ethernet" / Pincha en Activar el uso compartido de archivos e impresoras.

Desde la consola de comandos prueba esto:

```
msg * /server:192.168.1.42 "Buenos dias!"
```

Sustituye la IP por la IP destino y pulsa enter.

Posibles errores:

1 - Si te dice que el comando `msg` No se reconoce como comando interno o externo, lo más probable es que tú versión de windows desde donde lanzas el comando no sea PRO.

2 - Error 5 al obtener los nombres de las sesiones. La máquina destino no es versión PRO.

NOTA: He leído [aquí](https://www.trucoswindows.net/comando-net-send-windows-vista-msg/) que en el error 2, también puede ser debido al UAC de windows, en la máquina destino ejecuta desde el cm `C:\useraccountcontrolsettings` y establece el UAC lo más bajo posible. (En mi caso no he tenido que probar nada de esto)

Si nada de esto te funciona echa un vistazo a [ésta](https://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/) página, al final del todo habla de los errores, y cómo solución explica editar el registro de windows, pero eso no lo he probado.

Comment: Genial, gracias por la respuesta, lastimosamente estoy buscando algo que funcione en la mayoria de los windows al menos, no sabes de alguna libreria en C que permita este tipo de interacciones en red ? o de alguna otra forma de lograrlo?

Comment: @WhySoBizarreCode si las versiones de windows son PRO debe funcionar. programa de mensajeria pues LAN Messenger.

Comment: el problema es que no son pros y buscaba una solucion que yo pudiera programar en c, en el caso de que no pueda hacerlo desde la cmd porque tengo pensado hacer un programa en base a eso. un programa propio por eso descarto la idea de lan messenger

Comment: si hay mas de un ordenador se puede enviar un mensaje a todos los ordenadores?????

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a contar lo que a mi me funciono, que como a ti quizás, yo hice lo que @nachfren menciona y me ocurrió el error "Error 5 al obtener los nombres de las sesiones".

Pero ya había investigado un poco acerca del tema y lo que me funciono fue una herramienta oficial de microsoft que se llama "PSTools" te invito a que veas algunos vídeos acerca de el para que veas su funcionamiento, sí es algo externo pero igual sigue funcionando via cmd y solo son unos archivos.

Bueno, cuando ya hayas entendido como usar el psexec ya podrás hacer casi todo remotamente desde el cmd, para enviar un mensaje al pc remoto escribe el siguiente comando en el cmd siguiendo los pasos y la logica del PSTools **" psexec \IP -u HOSTNAME\Administrador -p PASSWORD -s msg * /server:IP "MENSAJE EJEMPLO!" "**

Las siglas como IP, PASSWORD, HOSTNAME, MENSAJE EJEMPLO, los debes cambiar segun tus datos pues.

Espero que te sirva, a mi me funciono bien, bueno estuve dias indagando he hice muchos cambios antes.
Si no te funciona ha de ser porque te falta modificar todo lo que yo modifique antes, pero primero prueba con esto.

GearVnzla.